# Geocache on click event without map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm working on a MVC asp.net project. On page #1 I need to post long and lat coordinates (the user's address) so the server can return the proper information to be displayed on page #2's google map.

I'm using Google Map Javascript API V3 on page #2, and I was hoping to use it on page #1.

I am using this code...and sometimes it works, and other times it doesn't. It usually works when I have it in debug mode. So some sort of timing issue I'm guess. I cannot figure it out.

```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   function initialize() {
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   }

   function submitClick() {
     var address = "Amsterdam, Netherlands";
     geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
       var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
       alert(lat + " and " + lng)
     } else {
       alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
     }
     });
```

I'm still new to the google map api, so I assume I'm just using it the wrong way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a timing issue. The page was trying to post before google could come back. I now post the page with javascript when google comes back.